# Select number of deleted records with t-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I can't seem to figure out how to select the number of previously deleted records with SQL Server 2008. Is it something like this?

```
DELETE FROM [table] WHERE [id]=10
SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()
```

Comment: While `@@RowCount` will give you the number of rows, you can also use an `OUTPUT` clause to get any data from the rows, e.g. the `id` values.  `OUTPUT` can be used with `INSERT`, `UPDATE` and `DELETE` and provides access to both before and after values in the case of `UPDATE`.  A tool well worth having in your pocket.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use `SELECT @@ROWCOUNT` immediately after the `DELETE` statement. You can [read more about `@@ROWCOUNT` on MSDN](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187316.aspx):

> ## `@@ROWCOUNT`
>
> Returns the number of rows affected by the last statement.
>
> ### Remarks
>
> ...
>
> **Data manipulation language (DML) statements set the `@@ROWCOUNT` value to the number of rows affected by the query and return that value to the client.** The DML statements may not send any rows to the client.

Note that I say "immediately after" because other statements can change the value of `@@ROWCOUNT`, even if they don't affect rows, per se:

> `DECLARE CURSOR` and `FETCH` set the `@@ROWCOUNT` value to 1.
>
> ...
>
> Statements such as `USE`, `SET <option>`, `DEALLOCATE CURSOR`, `CLOSE CURSOR`, `BEGIN TRANSACTION` or `COMMIT TRANSACTION` reset the `ROWCOUNT` value to 0.

Comment: Thanks. I knew I was missing something simple :)

Answer (score 2):

You can also [`SET NOCOUNT OFF`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa259204%28v=sql.80%29.aspx).

Remarks

When SET NOCOUNT is ON, the count (indicating the number of rows affected by a Transact-SQL statement) is not returned. When SET NOCOUNT is OFF, the count is returned.

Answer (score 0):

When debugging a stored procedure, I generally use this code snippet below:

```
DELCARE @Msg varchar(30)
...
SELECT @Msg = CAST(@@ROWCOUNT AS VARCHAR(10)) + ' rows affected'
RAISERROR (@Msg, 0, 1) WITH NOWAIT
```

I use it before and after an operation, like for a delete.  I'll put a number in the message to keep track of which snippet I'm on in the code.  It's very helpful when you are dealing with a large stored procedure with lots of lines of code.