# How to verify if a row has been deleted in SQL server

Tags: c++, sql-server, delete-row

I have a requirement where in i have to log a message in C++ code only if a row has been actually deleted from a table. Is there a way to get a confirmation message from SQL server 2012 that the delete statement actually deleted a row? Count (*) wont help since there are multiple clients who will be filling data into the table . So cannot rely on before and after  count.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can use `create trigger` to set up a stored procedure to be executed when a delete happens in the table of interest. That can do pretty much any/all the usual SQL things.

Comment: I second Jerry's comment. `INSERT INTO LogTable SELECT Whatever FROM deleted;` in a [AFTER DELETE trigger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189799.aspx) will probably fit the bill.

Comment: Thank you . Will try this. However , i am sceptical about the performance degradation due to the addition of a trigger.

Answer (score 4):

I personally use very straightforward approach.

When I delete a single row from a table I know its primary key, its `ID`. I use this primary key value in the `DELETE ... WHERE ...` statement. Then I do `SELECT ... WHERE ...` with the same `ID` and check how many rows it returns. If there are no rows returned I'm sure that the row has been deleted successfully. Or use `SELECT COUNT(*) WHERE ...` with that `ID` and check the count.

I use this approach is cases where I have a lot of child tables related to the table from which I'm deleting a row. All related tables have foreign keys and referential integrity constraints configured. All constraints are simple `CHECK CONSTRAINT` without cascade delete. If user really needs to delete a row from a master table he has to delete all child rows at first. If there are still related child rows when a user tries to delete from master, the delete will fail due to referential constraints.

Also, there is [@@ROWCOUNT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-AU/library/ms187316.aspx) or [ROWCOUNT_BIG](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-AU/library/ms181406.aspx):

> Returns the number of rows affected by the last statement. If the
>   number of rows is more than 2 billion, use ROWCOUNT_BIG.

Use `SELECT @@ROWCOUNT` immediately after the `DELETE` statement.

See this question: [Select number of deleted records with t-SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14300671/select-number-of-deleted-records-with-t-sql)

Comment: Thank you . This looks much better since it directly returns the row count. Will update once i use it.

Comment: @Ragas I'm glad it was useful for you. Mark this answer as accepted to help others with similar question.

Comment: So, if I delete the most recent row with ID of 10 and immediately insert another one, is it guaranteed that the inserted row will have an ID of 11 and not 10 again? If so, what is this feature called?

Comment: @Lukas, your question has little to do with the original question. In SQL Server I use a feature called `IDENTITY` for what you describe.